# archive oracle table using shrink space

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, archive

for the archiving purpose i need to delete the data from a table but as delete will not free up space a lot of data is occupied .To save this i have figured out a solution to use shrink space command provided by oracle.
But this requires row movement to be enabled.

So my question are below:
1. is it a good idea to enable row movement for using shrink space command.
2. Can we just enable the row movement for running shrink space command and then disable it again 
3. or we should leave row movement enabled and run shrink space command as and when required(say once a week).

Answer (score 1):

Are you deleting all of the data on the table or just some part of it? If you are deleting all of it you could just truncate it, freeing up all of the space allocated for the tables and indexes in a very fast way:

```
truncate table t;
```

If you are not deleting of all it, the row movement approach should be ok (any of the 3 options) but you would have to test concurrent access to this table. Is there a chance someone else would try to update/insert this table at the same time of your maintenance? My guess is that this could be a problem.

So another approach could be partition the table based on your purge criteria. For example, if you will erase the data older than 3 months, you could have the table partitioned by month and delete only the partitions you wont't need anymore. This is in fact what partitions were made for, to easy maintenance of data.

Comment: no concurrent access would be there ..as this is weekly exercise and at that time no insert or update would be there